# Image Auto Slider using JSON

Tags: android, json

Making **Image** `auto slider`, i have written code `to parse JSON` but still using `drawable` images

Actually i am `concern`, How to use `online images` in **slideshow** instead of `drawables`

Please `clear` to me because if `same kind` of **problem** occurs in future so i will be able to `make changes`.

check my code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;
public int currentimageindex = 0;
ImageView slidingimage;

// using drawable images
// in place of these static images, how can i use my arraylist 
// along with DownloadImageTask class, i have written posted below
private int[] IMAGE_IDS = {
        R.drawable.splash0,
        R.drawable.splash1, 
        R.drawable.splash2,
        R.drawable.splash3
    };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
    // execute AsyncTask
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");

    // handler to set duration and to upate animation
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {             
            AnimateandSlideShow();              
        }
    };

    int delay = 0000;
    int period = 4000;

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {
         mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
    }
    }, delay, period);
}

// AsyncTask to get data from server
class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();           
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Actors actor = new Actors();

                    actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));
                    Log.d("image: ", object.getString("image"));

                    actorsList.add(actor);

                }
                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

// method to show slide show
private void AnimateandSlideShow() {
    slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);           
    currentimageindex++;                
}

// method to dowload online images
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView3_Left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat:**

```
10-09 05:21:34.636: D/image:(735): http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/brad.jpg
10-09 05:21:34.636: D/image:(735): http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/cruise.jpg
10-09 05:21:34.636: D/image:(735): http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/johnny.jpg
10-09 05:21:34.636: D/image:(735): http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jolie.jpg
10-09 05:21:34.666: D/image:(735): http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/tom.jpg
10-09 05:21:34.666: D/image:(735): http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/will.jpg
```

Comment: what does the above code gives as output?

Comment: i posted my whole the code, and getting image urls from parsed JSON, and wrote code to download images as well, but don't how to use json urls in activity in place of drawables @mtetno

Comment: @Sophie In String arrayList your images are stored???

Comment: @X'Factor i made changes in my code, my mean now i used ArrayList as well, please check now

Comment: @Sophie Did you check this https://github.com/marvinlabs/android-slideshow-widget/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/marvinlabs/widget/slideshow/demo/SlideShowActivity.java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my code. I use View Flipper

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> actorsList;
ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    actorsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // execute AsyncTask
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");

    // handler to set duration and to upate animation
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AnimateandSlideShow();
        }
    };

    int delay = 500;
    int period = 4000;

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
        }
    }, delay, period);



}

  // AsyncTask to get data from server
  class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
    dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
    dialog.show();
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {

        //------------------>>
        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (status == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");

            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

              //  Actors actor = new Actors();
                actorsList.add(object.getString("image"));
             //   actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));
                Log.d("image: ", object.getString("image"));

             //   actorsList.add(actor);

            }
            return true;
        }

        //------------------>>

    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    dialog.cancel();
    if(result == false){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
    else{
        setFlipperImage( actorsList);
       }
    }
  }
  private void setFlipperImage(ArrayList<String> actorsList) {

 for(int i=0;i<actorsList.size();i++){
 Log.i("Set Filpper Called", actorsList.get(i).toString()+"");
 ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
// image.setBackgroundResource(res);
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
.load(actorsList.get(i).toString())
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.into(image);
 viewFlipper.addView(image);
 }
}
// method to show slide show
 private void AnimateandSlideShow() {
 viewFlipper.showNext();
 }}
```

> And i use Picasso to load the images....